# Cannot hit grpc server after successfully deploying to cloud run

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-run

Similar situation to [what was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207914/run-a-python-grpc-server-on-google-cloud-run), however the solution described there do not work in my case. I want to run a grpc server on google cloud run, and be able to call it. I have a basic python grpc server that works fine and is able to be called by my client when running the `gcr.io` image on localhost with `docker run`. However, after successfully deploying to google cloud run, and with the server listening on port 8080 (I logged it), I am no longer able to reach the server with my client code.

I receive the following:

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "DNS resolution failed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1591245267.073965000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3981,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1591245267.073946000","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":214,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1591245267.073945000","description":"DNS resolution failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":357,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1591245267.073882000","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Domain name not found","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1591245267.059636000","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Domain name not found","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244}]}]}]}]}"
>
```

my server code is as follows:

```
def serve():
    # expected port from google cloud run is 8080
    port = os.getenv('PORT')
    if not port:
        port = server_port
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:{port}'.format(port=port))
    server.start()
    logger.info('listening on port {port}'.format(port=port))
    server.wait_for_termination()
```

my client code, I have tried both

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('<the .run.app url on my cloud run service>:8080')
stub = my_service_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(channel)
request = my_service_pb2.MyEndpointRequest(
    test='hello'
)
response = stub.MyEndpoint(request)
print(response)
```

and

```
with grpc.secure_channel('<the .run.app url on my cloud run service>:8080', grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()) as channel:
    stub = my_service_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(channel)
    request = my_service_pb2.MyEndpointRequest(
        test='hello'
    )
    response = stub.MyEndpoint(request)
    print(response)
```

both of which do not work and gives me the same error that I wrote above.

Furthermore, when I `ping <the .run.app url on my cloud run service>` on the command line I get `Name or service not known`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Managed to solve it, the solution was to remove the `https://` prefix from the url shown on the cloud run service and use the `443` port instead of `8080`

```
with grpc.secure_channel(
        '<url without https:// prefix>:443',
        grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(),
) as channel:
    stub = my_service_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(channel)
    request = my_service_pb2.MyEndpointRequest(
        test='hello'
    )
    response = stub.MyEndpoint(request)
    print(response)
```